# Loops in Handlebars

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, handlebars.js

I have an array of tracks coming from a database that I want to display in a div.
More specifically I need to put every two of them in a bootstrap row. I can easily do it in the controller JS file by first collecting all in a fragment element and then use a loop to put them into the rows and then in the target div but I am wondering if it would be possible to do it directly while producing them in handlebars?
Here is the handlebars template:

```
{{#if result}}
{{#each result}}
<div class="playlist-item col-xs-4">
    <a href="#/user/{{username}}/playlist/{{id}}" class="no-style">
        <h3 class="result-title">{{title}}</h3>
        <p class="result-description">{{description}}</p>
        <img class="result-image img-circle" src="{{img}}">
    </a> 
    <br>
<a type="button" id="{{id.videoId}}" class="btn btn-default btn-remove" 
href="#/user/{{username}}/playlist/{{id}}/remove-from-playlist">Remove from 
playlist</a>
</div>
{{/each}}
{{else}}
<h4>You currently have no tracks in your playlist</h4>
{{/if}}
```

Here is the JS:

```
showPlaylist() {
    return Promise.all([
        userController.loadPlaylist(),
        templates.loadTemplate('playlist'),
    ])
    .then(([tracks, template]) => {
        let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment()
        let div = document.createElement('DIV');
        div.innerHTML = template(tracks);
        div = [...div.children];
        let len = div.length
        while(div.length > 0) {
            let row = document.createElement('div')
            row.className = 'row'
            let col = div.splice(0,2)
            row.append(col[0])
            if(col[1]) {
                row.append(col[1])
            }
            len -= 2;
            fragment.append(row)
        }
        $('#container').html(fragment)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to group your items into rows, but you would need to use a custom helper function to do it.

We will need to create a [block helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html) that takes an array of items, breaks the array into rows of specified number of columns, and then applies the block "row" template to each row. If we were to call our block helper "eachRow", the resulting template might look like the following:

```
{{#eachRow result 2}}
    <div class="row">
        {{#each columns}}
            <div class="playlist-item col-xs-4">
                {{!-- TODO: Rest of item template goes here. --}}
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
{{/eachRow}}
```

Notice that we still use the item template within a regular Handlebars `#each` block. Except now the `#each` is wrapped within a "row" template block. The `2` is a parameter that will be passed to our helper that is to be the number of columns in each row.

Next, we will write our helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('eachRow', function (items, numColumns, options) {
    var result = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i += numColumns) {
        result += options.fn({
            columns: items.slice(i, i + numColumns)
        });
    }

    return result;
});
```

This helper simply iterates over our source array in increments of `numColumns` and for each iteration applies our "row" block template, passing the array of items (`columns`) that are to render in that row. The helper concatenates the rows and returns the result.

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/zcowdhvc/) for reference.

Comment: Great! It is a much more elegant solution as I thought. Thanks for your help!